# What is the best way to combine local and global state

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

I have this global State

```
type GlobalState a = State Int a
```

but one function needs its own local state and access to the GlobalState

```
type LocalState a = State [String] a
```

But I'm not sure now to combine them.

Right now I just add local state to the global

```
type GlobalState a = State (Int, [String]) a
```

It works fine, but I don't think it's right because I only need local state in one function.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [monad stack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State.html) of two `State`s:

```
type LocalState a = [String]
type GlobalState a = [String]
newtype MyState a = StateT GlobalState (State LocalState) a
```

Comment: I can read GlobalState with `get` but how can I read LocalState?

Comment: I've created an example using this approach here: http://lpaste.net/177413

Comment: @ais Use `lift` to perform actions in the inner monad.